# how to write certain variables in a list to the console C#

Tags: c#, list, console.writeline

```
Stylist stylist1 = new Stylist(); // creates new stylist
stylist1.FirstName = "john";
stylist1.LastName = "smith";
stylist1.Phone = "123456789";
stylist1.Email = "js@123.456";
stylist1.Rate = "123";

Stylist stylist2 = new Stylist(); // creates new stylist
stylist2.FirstName = "jane";
stylist2.LastName = "doe";
stylist2.Phone = "987654321";
stylist2.Email = "jd@987.654";
stylist2.Rate = "456";

List<Stylist> stylists = new List<Stylist>(); // creates stylist 
list

stylists.Add(stylist1);
stylists.Add(stylist2);
```

i want to display the contents of the list to the console but i only want to display `FirstName` and `LastName`, how do i go about doing this? i have also made a custome class called Stylist

```
public class Stylist
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT

i am able to write what i need if i write each one out separately from the list

```
Console.WriteLine(stylist1.FirstName + " " + stylist1.LastName);
```

i have tried using a `foreach`

```
foreach (object i in stylists)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

but this only prints "ACW_Programming2.Stylist

ACW_Programming2 is the project name

Comment: Have you done any research at all on this?  Tried anything?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach (var i in stylists)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.FirstName + " " + i.LastName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternate to Giorgi's answer you can override the ToString method of Stylist

```
public class Stylist
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FirstName + " " + LastName;
    }
}
```

Then do what you did

```
foreach (Stylist i in stylists)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```